# How to subclass a class in ObjectiveC correctly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, subclass

I write a UITextfield with code in file called login.m

```
    _textfield1 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 60, self.view.frame.size.width-50*2, 44)];
    _textfield1.placeholder = @"email";
    _textfield1.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f];
    _textfield1.delegate = self;
    UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:_textfield1.bounds byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerTopLeft|UIRectCornerTopRight cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(4, 4)];
    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    maskLayer.frame = _textfield1.bounds;
    maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
    _textfield1.layer.mask = maskLayer;
    [self.view addSubview:_textfield1];
```

and i subclass UITextfield with name 'NewTextField', NewTextField.h

```
     #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
     @interface NewTextField : UITextField
     @end
```

NewTextField.m

```
     #import "NewTextField.h"
     @implementation NewTextField
     - (void)setMaskView:(UIView *)maskView {
       UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath   bezierPathWithRoundedRect:maskView.bounds byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerBottomLeft|UIRectCornerBottomRight cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(4, 4)];
       CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
       maskLayer.frame = maskView.bounds;
       maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
       maskView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
    }
    @end
```

in file login.m, i update code

```
   _textfield1 = [[NewTextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 60, self.view.frame.size.width-50*2, 44)];
   _textfield1.placeholder = @"email";
   _textfield1.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f];
   _textfield1.delegate = self;
   [_textfield1 setMaskView:_textfield1];
   [self.view addSubview:_textfield1];
```

it works, but i don't think it is a right way. so how can I subclass a class in right way?

Comment: Why do you think it's wrong?  What problems are you observing?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `_textfield1 = [[NewTextField alloc].... ` after you updated your code?

Comment: @Avi  here is so bizarrerie in line [_textfield1 setMaskView:_textfield1];

Answer (score 0):

In NewTextField.m instead of - (void)setMaskView:(UIView *)maskView write a initializer method as bellow,

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath   bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.bounds byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerBottomLeft|UIRectCornerBottomRight cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(4, 4)];
        CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
        maskLayer.frame = self.bounds;
        maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
        self.layer.mask = maskLayer;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically there is no problem with subclassing UITextField like you've done, maybe I'm stating the obvious because you told us it works :D.

However if you plan just to add a mask to a UITextField, it feels unnecessary to subclass a UITextField, maybe just create helper method or a category to add a the mask to the textfield, that seems like a cleaner approach.